# How to add DateTime Scale slider with multiple date click event angularjs using API?

Tags: angularjs, api, datetime, date-range, timeline

I want a Date timeline with multiple date clicks using API JSON data. I have added range slider not able to add multiple dates on slider:

[image: Like this image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want a Date time scale like this with multiple dates. All dates come from API and print on timeline. Also, every date below should have a click point. which point will click date will select also when date select will change another event happen.